# How do I deserialize YAML documents from external sources and have full access on class members?

Tags: ruby, serialization, yaml

In Ruby any object can be transferred, i.e. serialized, to a YAML document by saving the output of the "`to_yaml`" method to a file. Afterwards, this YAML file can be read again, i.e. deserialized, by using the `YAML::load` method. Moreover, one has full access on all members of the underlying class/object.

All of this is valid as long I'm using Ruby as a single platform. Once I serialize objects in Java and deserialize them under Ruby, I cannot access the object any more because of a `NoMethodError` exception. This is due to to the way objects/local data types are named under different systems.

Given a Ruby class "Car":

```
# A simple class describing a car
#
class Car
  attr :brand, :horsepower, :color, :extra_equipment

  def initialize(brand, horsepower, color, extra_equipment)
    @brand = brand
    @horsepower = horsepower
    @color = color
    @extra_equipment = extra_equipment
  end  
end
```

Creating a simple instance:

```
# creating new instance of class 'Car' ...
porsche = Car.new("Porsche", 180, "red", ["sun roof", "air conditioning"])
```

Calling `porsche.to_yaml` results in the following output:

```
--- !ruby/object:Car 
brand: Porsche
color: red
extra_equipment: 
- sun roof
- air conditioning
horsepower: 180
```

I test deserialization by loading the YAML output:

```
# reading existing yaml file from file system
sample_car = YAML::load(File.open("sample.yaml"))
puts sample_car.brand # returns "Porsche"
```

This works as expected, but now let's assume the YAML document was produced by a different system and lacks any reference to Ruby, although having a yaml-conform object description, "`!Car`", instead of "`!ruby/object:Car`":

```
--- !Car 
brand: Porsche
color: red
extra_equipment: 
- sun roof
- air conditioning
horsepower: 180
```

This code:

```
# reading existing yaml file from file system
sample_car = YAML::load(File.open("sample.yaml"))
puts sample_car.brand # returns "Porsche"
```

returns this exception:

```
/path/yaml_to_object_converter.rb.rb:27:in `<main>':
undefined method `brand' for #<YAML::DomainType:0x9752bec> (NoMethodError)
```

Is there a way to deal with objects defined in "external" YAML documents?

Comment: maybe this will help: http://blog.bytemine.net/2009/12/07/yaml-in-java-and-ruby-welcome-yamlbeans

Comment: Is "class members" (from the title) a Java term?

Comment: @Andrew: I admit that it's rather Java terminology and thus a bit imprecise in this Ruby context. I meant class variables and class methods.

Comment: I can't see any class variables or class methods here - just instance variables and instance methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me `sample_car` in the IRB shell evaluates to:

```
=> #<Syck::DomainType:0x234df80 @domain="yaml.org,2002", @type_id="Car", @value={"brand"=>"Porsche", "color"=>"red", "extra_equipment"=>["sun roof", "air conditioning"], "horsepower"=>180}>
```

Then I issued `sample_car.value`:

```
=> {"brand"=>"Porsche", "color"=>"red", "extra_equipment"=>["sun roof", "air conditioning"], "horsepower"=>180}
```

Which is a Hash. This means, that you can construct **your** Car object by adding a class method to `Car` like so:

```
def self.from_hash(h)
  Car.new(h["brand"], h["horsepower"], h["color"], h["extra_equipment"])
end
```

Then I tried it:

```
porsche_clone = Car.from_hash(sample_car.value)
```

Which returned:

```
=> #<Car:0x236eef0 @brand="Porsche", @horsepower=180, @color="red", @extra_equipment=["sun roof", "air conditioning"]>
```

That's the ugliest way of doing it. There might be others. =)

**EDIT (19-May-2011): BTW, Just figured a lot easier way:**

```
def from_hash(o,h)
  h.each { |k,v|
    o.send((k+"=").to_sym, v)
  }
  o
end
```

For this to work in your case, your constructor must not require parameters. Then you can simply do:

```
foreign_car = from_hash(Car.new, YAML::load(File.open("foreign_car.yaml")).value)
puts foreign_car.inspect
```

...which gives you:

```
#<Car:0x2394b70 @brand="Porsche", @color="red", @extra_equipment=["sun roof", "air conditioning"], @horsepower=180>
```

Comment: I don't really consider that ugly. I consider it defensive programming to reduce any objects down to their base types and send those. It is icing on the YAML cake that it tries to help us by sending objects, but that feature also gets in the way. Go to the basic values and the data should move across without problems.

Comment: Well, I only said it because I am sure there is a Gem out there who can automate the process even more, without the dev having to add class methods. ;) Otherwise the method is neat.

Comment: Yeah, a gem does streamline the code that calls it but I think that's just slathering the cake with more icing to hide the fact that the cake is lumpy. :-) I agree with you though, reusing the gem is a good way to go about it. I'd probably have added a `to_yaml` method to the classes in question, but that's one of my many brain flaws.

Comment: I also agree that the programmer must have knowledge about the class (here "Car") and its properties. Then he can implement a "from_hash" method and "reconstruct" the object. But as far as I can judge this, there is no easy out-of-the-box method allowing to read yaml documents describing objects from non-Ruby systems. Especially objects that are strongly nested would take a lot of time.

Comment: For example consider: --- !Car 
engine: !DefaultEngineClass
  valves: 6
  tolerance: !!float '1.39154E13' 
  crank: !DefaultCrankClass
    width: 100
    height: 200
    material: !DefaultMaterialClass
      type: steel
      manufacturer: West Coast Car Parts

Comment: BTW, forgot to comment here, but I updated the answer with a much nicer way. No idea if something like that is somewhere in a Gem, though.